# Initialize ImageView with Image Name

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to know how to make an image object with `UIImage.init(named:)` for and then assign it to an image view:

```
var userSelectedImage = 4
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image\(userSelectedImage)")
```

How can make it so I can initialize a `UIImageView` with an image name like below?

```
var userSelectedImageView = 3
UIImageView(named: "imageView\(userSelectedImage)")
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's what your object properties are for. You can store your image view in an array or dictionary of `[String:UIImageView]`

Comment: why on earth you want to do something like this? Your UIImageView() hasn't been initialized yet.

Comment: @Josh his goal is pretty straightforward, he would like to make a convenience initializer to improve productivity and readability

Comment: You are already setting the image in the initializer! Then why set the image again?! -
UIimageView(named: "imageView\(userSelectedImage)").image = image

Comment: His original example code is odd but the question is quite apparent

Comment: Nope, he is quite clear! He wants to find a fictitious ImageView as apparent in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make an [extension](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html)

```swift
extension UIImageView {

    convenience init(named name: String) {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
        image = UIImage(named: name)
    }

}
```

Extensions can be used to significantly improve your productivity and readability; great question. I hope you come to love Swift extensions as much as I do!

Comment: @seemoretheman please let me know if this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you ask correctly. You want an UIImage, that you can then add to an UIImageView?

Initializing a UIImage:

```
let myImage = UIImage(named: "nameOfImage")
```

Assign the image to your UIImageView:

```
imageView.image = myImage
```

You could also do it all at once:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "nameOfImage"))
```

Hope this helps :)